# Admin panel in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking at switching from Code Igniter to Laravel.

We deploy a large amount of sites, using our custom admin panel.

This is setup as two installations of Code Igniter,

You basically have (simplified, we actually use HMVC on both the main site and the admin panel, but this gets the point across)

```
index.php
assets
system
application
  config
  controllers
  models
  views    
admin
  index.php
  assets
  application 
    config 
    controllers
    models
    views
```

And the admin install is setup to load the config files (e.g. `database.php`) from the main site via includes.

All our models for the main site use the models from the admin panel via include and then extend them, allowing us to have the functions that are specific to the main site in the main site only.

This has worked quite well for us, but now we are switching to Laravel we are wondering if there is a better way of doing this, We use the admin panel to manage several "modules" such as a blog, shopping cart, property manager, which are all drop ins.

Essentially we want to be able to:

- keep the separation of the main site from the admin panel clear so we can use the admin panel on any of our sites.
- Be able to still drop in bundles (e.g. a blog bundle).
- Idealistically we would like to have a shared bundles folder between the admin panel and the main site with three folders. `admin`/`main`/`shared` so a bundle is self contained.

What would the best way of implementing this be in laravel?

Comment: @Charles - Why were those tags not relevant? it's about two different frameworks - hence `frameworks` | it's about an admin panel used to power multiple sites hence `multisite` and it's about admin panels hence `admin`

Comment: Tags aren't keywords.  "Frameworks" and "admin" are noise.  They're basically useless meta dumping grounds.  Go check out their question lists, you will find that the listed questions have nothing in common. Their use should be discouraged. "multisite" has no other questions, it was created unnecessarily as part of a wordpress question.  This is a *Laravel* question.

Comment: Fair call then, Just wanted some clarification as to why they were removed, now I know not to use them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already pondered this, but I think it would be best to use an admin bundle, considering that bundles are all part of the core system. It's good for SoC and for simplicity (ease of use).

The admin panel could then find all bundles (except itself, of course) to read and write configuration entries, such as those of a blog bundle.

An alternative would be to place the admin panel into your main application, by routing specific commands to various admin controllers (don't forget that you can put controllers into sub-folders). For example, you could route, using `routes.php`, `admin/pages/edit/152` to the `pages.php` controller in `application/controllers/admin/`. You could even manage your various bundles/snap-ins using this approach, by means of scanning the bundles directory, as mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

I was also switching from CI to Laravel and found that basic Admin Panel are there in Laravel but not a proper solutions to Handle Data while generating CRUD's

Check LaraAdmin is a Open source Laravel Admin Panel / CMS which can be used as Admin Backend, Data Management Tool or CRM boilerplate for Laravel with features like CRUD Generation, Module Manager, Media, Menus, Backups and much more.

Documentation: http://laraadmin.com/docs/1.0

Source Code: https://github.com/dwijitsolutions/laraadmin

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can change your Apache configuration so each site is a virtual host one directory up from Laravel? This way each site would be its own "html" directory and you would not really need to change anything in Laravel; the line in index.php will do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
require '../paths.php';
```

This is assuming all your sites run on the same machine or cluster so your system would look like this

```
assets
system
application
  config
  controllers
    admin
    site1
    site2
  models
    admin
    site1
    site2
  views    
    admin
    site1
    site2
html_site1
html_site2
```

however if you just want to have the admin panel be its own application, you could just copy the contents of html into the admin directory, alter the mod_rewrite or .htaccess for that dir and then change

```
require '../paths.php';
```

to

```
require 'path/to/admin/paths.php';
```

and it will use a completly different laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravella (a CMS, CRUD package for laravel)

https://github.com/laravella/laravella/releases

Whether you use Laravella or not, create a package for each site which overrides the main site's classes.  That way you can keep each site is in its own source control repository.